# Оптимизировать запрос к базе данных

Tags: django, django-filter

Есть 2 модели: `Credit`, `CreditPayment`. Вторая связана с первой через `FK` (`Inline`). Есть фильтр по `CreditPayment`. Как грамотно вытащить все `Credit`, связанные с отфильтрованными `CreditPayment`?

```
CreditPayment.objects.filter(amount_from__lte=sum)
```

Если делать через `.values('credit', flat=True)`, то получаю список *айди* связанных объектов Credit, а надо бы список именно *объектов*...

```
conditions = CreditPayment.objects.filter(amount_from__lte=sum).values_list('credit', flat=True).distinct()
credits = []
for i in conditions:
    credits.append(Credit.objects.get(id=i))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
credits = Credit.objects.filter(id__in=CreditPayment.objects.filter(amount_from__lte=sum).values('credit__id').distinct())
```

Answer (score -1):

Можно так:

```
credits = Credit.objects.filter(credit_payment__amount__lte=sum).select_related('credit_payment')
```

Но это при условии, что у поля credit не переопределён атрибут `related_name`. Если переопределён, то вместо `credit_payment` нужно подставить Ваше значение.

Что такое `select_related` можно посмотреть здесь https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Comment: у `Credit` нет аргумента `creditpayment`

Comment: я имел ввиду, что вместо credit_payment Вы должны подставить название поля для обратной связи c моделью Credit. Т.е. если у модели CreditPayment есть поле credit, то для конкретного Credit-а Вы можете определить к какому имеенно CreditPayment он относится.